# Casting from "Double to Float" rounding off decimal places

Tags: c#, casting, floating-point

Can anyone please help me understand that why output for float is rounding off decimal ?

**Code -**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    float f = (float)Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble("270825.27000000000000"), 2);
    double d = Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble("270825.27000000000000"), 2);

    Console.WriteLine("Float  - " + f.ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("Double - " + d.ToString());

    Console.Read();
}
```

**Output -**

[image]

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Because a float isn't as precise as a double?

Comment: From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single: "A Single value has up to 7 decimal digits of precision, although a maximum of 9 digits is maintained internally."

Comment: Before assignment (casting) its the same value on the right side (`Math.Round(...)`). Don't obscure problem with "rounding" or something like this. You simply assigning `double` to `float` and as a result loosing *precision*.

Comment: Rohit float is not as precise as double. Only sometimes they can have more than 8 digit precisions. What is guaranteed is just 7-digit - which is your case.

Comment: Thanks everyone for quick responses and @Jon for the sweet link.

Answer (score 1):

you are casting double to float, so basicly you have:

1. conversion to **double** but should be **float**
2. rounding which is **double**
3. casting

   ```
    float f = (float)Math.Round(float.Parse("270825.27000000000000"), 2);
    double d = Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble("270825.27000000000000"), 2);    
    Console.WriteLine("Float  - " + f.ToString());    
    Console.WriteLine("Double - " + d.ToString());
   ```

results are:

> Float  - 270825.3
>
> Double - 270825.27

so use decimal

```
decimal f = (decimal)Math.Round(decimal.Parse("270825.27000000000000"), 2);
Console.WriteLine("Decimal  - " + f.ToString());
```

> 270825.27